# Is there a 100% command line utility for svn in windows?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, svn

I only want to access to `svn` by command line,

so [tortoise](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) is not what I want.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can find download links at http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows

Answer (score 4):

1. What clients can I get for windows? 
   Compare yourselves at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients (Wikipedia, Comparison of Subversion Clients). @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams suggested Tigris.org binaries. Tigris.org is the old website for Apache Subversion (formerly Subversion).

   I would suggest http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download (Silk SVN binaries).
2. Why subversion has something to do with Apache? 
   Subversion is one of the project selected from the Apache Incubator project. It is now one of the top-level projects in the Apache project. In addition, the project is in a apache-compatible license, and the server can run with Apache to provide HTTP based version control services.

Answer (score 0):

They are what I use at the moment:

1) Go to CollabNet (http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion) to download the package 'subversion' (current version 1.7.8). It includes all Subversion command-line binaries and an auto-update component.

2) use the svn command in cygwin

Answer (score -2):

Yes - 'Subversion Windows Installer' http://alagazam.net/

It's a binary windows build of Apache Subversion.  He is usually only a week or two behind the releases from Apache.

Comment: Please provide additional details - why should they try it, what does it provide?